# my timer stops working on random times - React

Tags: reactjs, timer

I have made a timer which works according to the time right now and stops when the minutes gets to -1 (right after 00:01) but sometimes the timers seems to just stop working on random times (might have something to do with the browser or the computer's screen going off?) this is my code and i would love to get some help <3

```
  const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState(['00']);
  const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState(['00']);

  const TimerHandler = (e) => { 
    if (timerMinutes != '00' || timerSeconds != '00') { 
      const Interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timerMinutes !== -1)  { 
        const timeNowSeconds = 60-new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {second: '2-digit'}); 
        setTimerSeconds(timeNowSeconds);
        clearInterval(Interval);
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(Interval);
        setTimerSeconds('00');
        setTimerMinutes('00');
        alert('new position added');
      }
      }, 980)
    }
    if (timerSeconds == '1') {
      setTimeout(() => {
      setTimerMinutes(timerMinutes-1);
      }, 1005);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why the mins values setting to -1? Shouldn't it stop at 0 or get reset?

Comment: You put the react tag in your question. Is this code running inside of a component? If so, could you share the component code as well.